# Image property not found in runtime PictureBox control c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Image property not found from the item variable. My code is -

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls) //Iterating all controls on form
{
    if (item is PictureBox)
    {
        if (item.Tag.ToString() == ipAddress + "OnOff")
        {
            MethodInvoker action = delegate
            { item.Image= }; //.Image property not shown
            item.BeginInvoke(action);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: if any of the answers sufficiently addressed your question, you may want to select it as the answer, so the question can be removed from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @Alex - Ok, I'm going to mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `item` variable still is of the type `Control`. Checking that the instance it is referencing is a `PictureBox` does not change that. You could change your code to:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls) //Iterating all controls on form
{
    var pb = item as PictureBox; // now you can access it a PictureBox, if it is one
    if (pb != null)
    {
        if (item.Tag.ToString() == ipAddress + "OnOff")
        {
            MethodInvoker action = delegate
            { 
                pb.Image =  ... // works now
            }; 
            bp.BeginInvoke(action);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Is the explanation why this works, and what you were doing didn't work, clear?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `as` operator, like so:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = item as PictureBox;

    if (pictureBox != null)
    {
        if (item.Tag.ToString() == ipAddress + "OnOff")
        {
            MethodInvoker action = delegate
            { item.Image= ... };
            item.BeginInvoke(action);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```